# CSS and repeating page headers not working

Tags: html, css

I've been trying some documented features of CSS3 to have headers repeat at the top of each page (at least at printing time) but that's not working, neither with Safari nor Firefox.

Would anyone have a clue about why?

Here is a simple non-working test below:

```
<html>
<head>
  <style type="text/css"> 
    #header{
      position: running(pageHeader);
    }
    @page {
        size: A4 portrait;
        margin: 2in;

        @top-left {
            content: "THIS IS ANOTHER NON-WORKING ATTEMPT";
        }
    }
    @page {
      @top-center {
        content: element(pageHeader);
      }
    }
    div.content {
        page-break-after: always;
    } 
  </style>
</head> 
<body>
  <div id='header'>THIS IS A NON-WORKING ATTEMPT TO HAVE THIS HEAD EVERY PAGE</div>
  <div class='content'>Content for a Page1, which is properly followed by a page-break</div>
  <div>Content for a Page2</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need it at printing time, why don't you try hiding it with a regular CSS rule and showing it with a `@media print` CSS rule? You probably can do this *and* make a different div that sticks to the top of the page (on a browser) and hide this new div on printing.

Comment: In fact I'd like it to work first. Then I'll see to differentiate the display with @media.
Do you, by chance, know how to repeating page headers work?

Comment: I know there's several issues with browsers and running element. Also, it seems strange that your header has an ID of `header` but yet you call for `element(pageHeader)` in your CSS. You might look into that (plus the fact that you have a trailing `</td></tr>` at the end of your second div - but that is likely not the issue here).

Comment: I've tried already with all header-related items identified as pageHeader but that's not fixing it (in fact, if I understood well, the element() call refers to what has been previously in a running() call, which happens for the Element #header, so in theory that should be it).
I've read that Safari does not support @page (anymore ?). So I'll probably abandon my attempts after a successful test with another browser (perhaps Opera).